# Any way to give names to each of a set of successive integers?

Tags: objective-c, int, naming-conventions

I have an `int` called `setupStage`. This is simply a value I increment at the completion of each stage, so I can say, `if (setupStage == 2)`, and I know that I am at the third stage (it defaults to 0).

Is there a way I can refer to these numbers in a better way? For example:

`if (setupStage == stageEnterName)`

Instead of having to refer to its actual raw `int` value.

It may be a misconception, but does what I am trying to achieve have anything to do with defining macros?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes!

Try this:

```
typedef enum {
    MyType0,
    MyType1,
    MyType2,
    MyType3
} MyType;
```

This is the same thing as this:

```
typedef enum {
    MyType0 = 0,
    MyType1,
    MyType2,
    MyType3
} MyType;
```

The values default to 0 at the first slot and then increment by 1 automatically. Note that the token names (MyTypeX) are arbitrary string values you set.

In this case they go from 0 to 3. Then you can say something like this:

```
if (setupStage == MyType3)
```

Which is identical to

```
if (setupStage == 3)
```

Comment: So here, `MyType` would represent `setupStage`? And how do I make `MyType1` equal to zero and `MyType2` equal to one etc?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you do want a macro like solution, and fortunately one exists.

```
STAGE_ONE = 0
STAGE_TWO = 1
STAGE_THREE = 2
# ...

if setupStage == STAGE_THREE:
```

will work.